# Read Source of Page that completes itself after reaching end of page

Tags: c#, browser

I wanted to write a Page parser for VK.com. My Problem is, that the page source contains only 50 Results, and the others are reloaded after reaching the end of the Page.

My Code until now:

```
    private void syncToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] information, title, artist;
        int i = 0;
        List<string> joint = new List<string>();
        information = info_basic(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
        title = info_title(information);
        artist = info_artist(information);
        foreach (string str in title)
        {
            joint.Add(artist[i] + " - " + title[i]);
            i++;
        }
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(joint.ToArray());
    }

    private string[] info_basic(string source)
    {
        string[] temps;
        List<string> sub = new List<string>();
        temps = Regex.Split(source, "<div class=\"play_btn fl_l\">");
        foreach (string str in temps)
        {
            sub.Add(str);
        }
        sub.RemoveRange(0, 1);
        return sub.ToArray();
    }
```

Important Code of Page:

http://csharp.bplaced.net/files/vk%20source.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to monitor traffic from page to vk.com when you scroll to the bottom
(for example, using fiddler http proxy), and find out how page is dynamically loaded.
Most probably this is done through ajax async calls from javascript.
And then, simulate same behavior in code to load entire page. HttpWebRequest class would work best for this task.

But since you are using webBrowser control, and probably it does all the work for loading the content - you can try to programmatically scroll the web browser control view, so that native js would fire and load content, stop when you reach the bottom, and then parse entire loaded page.

Comment: Thanks, but I found another way over the API to do this.